# Can I use a tortoise SVN repository on Linux, which is synchronized/distributed using dropbox without dumping?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository, tortoisehg, tortoisegit

On **Windows Vista** I use **Tortoise SVN**, and the SVN repository is backed up using **dropbox**. I have another machine which is running **Ubuntu**, and has the recent version of the SVN repository.

I would like to update the repository while working in Linux. I would like to use the command line to commit and checkout files from the repository initially created with Tortoise SVN, but I would like to do this without having to *dump* and *load* the whole repository which is quite large (~1GB).

Or would it be much wiser to move to a distributed version control system and end all these issues? I thought that using tortoise HG / GIT, on bitbucket could possibly be a solution.

Comment: It makes sense to read SVNBook http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it **wrong** and it seems that you are confusing [**Working Copy**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy) and [**Repository**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.repository) terms! I'd like to note that `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` are not related to your issue BTW.

TortoiseSVN repository is a regular Subversion repo. You can access the repository that's located on Dropbox both from Linux and Windows machines via `file://` protocol.

The ultimate and correct answer is to install a SVN server so you could access your repositories from both machines. Or move your repositories to some private Subversion hosting, at least.

Comment: thanks for this. So if I understand, I can use the working copies normally, and commit to the TortoiseSVN created repo on Linux that is synched by drop box in a local copy? And then when back in windows with the synched repo from dropbox, I can use TortoiseSVN again and all is good?

Comment: @Vass yep, this is correct. However I still strongly advise you to consider some real server solution. In-house SVN server or a hosted one will do.

Comment: great. Which do you recommend for hosting? I don't have an in-house server, I have two laptops. What do I gain from hosting providers?

Comment: @vass Can't recommend any, as for me they are all the same. Google it :) You'll gain authorization, authentication, you could invite other developers etc. (Most of the features in-house SVN server has will be available there).

Comment: one last question, can you give me an idea how to get started on this with the SVN repo being a directory on the machine?

Comment: `svnadmin dump <pathtorepo> > repo.dump` then load it to the hosting through their web control panel or something. For more detail check the SVNBook at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate